# jQuery: setInterval not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to run a setInterval via jQuery. The problem is that it is breaking my jQuery script completely. I suspect there is an error somewhere but I can't seem to find it, can you?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "admin-ajax.php",
    data : {action: "check_noti_log"},
    context: this,
    success:function(data){

         if(data.length == 0)
             // no new notification
         else
         {
             // the count is returned, insert it in the first a tag inside #wp-admin-bar-noti-bar list item
             jQuery('#wp-admin-bar-noti-bar').children().first().html(data);

             // change element id to new
             jQuery('#wp-admin-bar-noti-bar').attr('id','wp-admin-bar-noti-bar-new');
         }

    }
  });

 }, 60000);

});
```

Comment: You should describe the desired behavior in the text of the question.

Comment: @JamesSimpson Nothing works, not even my other scripts in my JS file when I add this. I suspect there is a missing bracket somewhere or similar.

Comment: Can you really have a if(x == y) with a comment under? Doesn't that break the execution, JS is awkward but this isn't possible in most other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what you missed:

`if(data.length == 0){` // This bracket

```
} // and the close one
```

Comment: What he missed was that he should have just said `if (data.length != 0)`.

Comment: You got it my friend!